# Why is this code was invalid by validator?

Tags: html, validation

I have code :

```
<ul>
<li>home</li><span class="divider"> | </span>
.....
</ul>
```

and

```
<ul><li>one</li> | <li>two</li> | <li>three</li></ul>
```

But [validator](http://validator.w3.org/) say it wrong. What should I do?

Comment: You hve text outside your `<li>` tags, which is not valid HTML inside a `<ul>` element. Either set up the dividers inside their own `<li>` elements, or look at using `border` CSS properties to create them.

Comment: By the way, the validator does not say "wrong". It says "Element span not allowed as child of element ul in this context" and "Contexts in which element span may be used: Where phrasing content is expected" and also "Content model for element ul: Zero or more li and script-supporting elements". Which would have answered your question.

Answer (score 4):

The allowed elements inside a `<ul>` is simply `<li>`:

> Permitted contents
>
> Zero or more li elements

http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/ul.html

If you want to add borders / piping, use CSS. Like this example (for simplicity)

```
<ul>
    <li style="border-right:solid 1px #000;">Home</li>
    <li style="border-right:solid 1px #000;">About Me</li>
</ul>
```

As you get more familiar with CSS, you'll find better ways to do that... and also not inline.

Comment: Just so my answer isn't misleading, like Rob G said, you can put `span` etc inside the `<li>`... I just prefer CSS option on the `li` itself.

Answer (score 0):

All tags directly beneath a `<ul>` tag must be `<li>` tags. These `<li>` tags can contain spans, but the `<ul>` itself should not.